# Is it possible to get the size of an hsqldb in-memory database?

Tags: hsqldb, in-memory-database

I am testing various serialization strategies for storing objects in an hsqldb database. Normally, I would use a file based database, but in my tests it is convenient for me to use an in-memory database.

Is there a way to get the size of such a database?

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking the JVM memory allocation before and after you populate the database.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

The total minus the free memory is the current memory usage.